# Точное позиционирование виджетов на разных устройствах

Tags: android, xml, design

Условно экран разделен на две части.
В нижней расположена картинка, а поверх нее несколько `TextView`. Эти `TextView` располагаются точно в определенных местах поверх картинки.

Я сделал `RelativeLayout`, внутри него картинка и к правому верхнему углу этой картинки привязаны `TextView`, соответственно с разными отступами. На девайсах с шириной больше *500px* все смотрится более-менее нормально, но при тесте на девайсах *480x800px* все улетает в тартарары.

Как сделать так чтоб везде все смотрелось нормально?

Разметка:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/maingloballayout"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/mainpic1080923"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/mainimage"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="10"
                android:id="@+id/wordstolearncount"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_marginRight="107dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/statusbarcolor"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="10"
                android:id="@+id/wordstorepeatcount"

                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="168dp"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/statusbarcolor"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="10"
                android:id="@+id/wordstorepeat2count"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_marginRight="237dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/statusbarcolor"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="10"
                android:id="@+id/wordstotestcount"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainimage"
                android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/statusbarcolor"/>



        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно согласен с @pavlofff. Есть только еще один совет - можно ресурс использовать один, а вот размеры - разные. Я заметил, что маржины у вас записаны как числа в формате дп - перенесите их все в димены и для каждого из размеров экрана задайте свои маржины, используя одноименные димены с разными значениями:)

Answer (score 1):

Точно спозиционировать виджеты на экране при одной разметке и огромном количестве размеров экранов, плотностей и разрешений у вас не получится.

Делайте отдельные разметки для разных плотностей экрана, это в некоторой степени компенсирует различные плотности и разрешения, но позиционирование будет все равно иметь определенные погрешности на разных устройствах (со специфическими экранами).

Создайте разметку отдельно для плотностей: `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi` и `xxxhdpi` с наилучшим расположением элементов для именно этой плотности и разместите свои разметки в папках: `/res/layout-hdpi/` , `/res/layout-xhdpi/` , `/res/layout-xxhdpi/` и `/res/layout-xxxhdpi/` соответственно. Имя файла разметки используйте одно и то же для всех вариантов. Система подберет нужный исходя из текущих параметров устройства.

Если точности позиционирования при таком решении будет все же недостаточно, то вам придется заниматься вычислениями для позиционирования виджетов (получать размеры экрана текущего устройства, определять позицию исходя из текущих размеров и тд. - чистая математика с геометрией)  и размещать их динамически из кода, а не разметкой.

Comment: К примеру, motorolla droid razr 540x960 240dpi показывает нормально, а samsung galaxy s2 480x800 с теми же 240dpi выводит совсем не то. да и при тесте на планшетах с любой плотностью все нормально. вот и непонятно почему так